# MySQL Java getting objects by a distinct field

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee

I need to return *java objects* from my database by distinct field. In my database I have *Country*, *State*, *City*. Now I have 2 records where they have the same data in the fields, but I only want to return distinct states in a country.

To clarify - I have two records with the same country and state. I only want to return one state instead of Washington twice for example. However, I need the object as opposed to returning the string of washington.

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r FROM Roster r where r.state = :state AND r.country = :country
```

What is happening is it will return all the duplicates because the objects are not distinct, where I just want one of each?

I apologise if I was not very clear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit: I need the objects because I am using them to populate a results table.

edit2: 
My create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `roster` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clientName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `tDomain` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `tSubDomain` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tReferenceId` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `endDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `startTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `endTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `mobileNumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `officeNumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `availability` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Everything up to tReferenceID is likely to be common. The rest is going to be unique. I am toying with the idea of splitting the table into two. But that would involve quite a hefty rewrite.

Comment: are you using hibernate or jpa ?

Comment: I had an idea based on your old answer @Alejandro. Because I am using a list of strings to populate my drop down, I use a set instead. I will have to test it. Thanks for the poke in the right direction (hopefully)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't know JPA if it fell on my head. So I fumble after this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.Country,r.State,r.City 
FROM Roster r 
where r.state = :state AND r.country = :country
```

**Edit**:

Ok clearly that was wrong for an object :>

how about

```
create table roster
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    country varchar(100) not null,
    state varchar(100) not null,
    city varchar(100) not null
);

insert roster (country,state,city) values ('usa','kentucky','louisville');
insert roster (country,state,city) values ('usa','illinois','chicago');
insert roster (country,state,city) values ('usa','kentucky','louisville');
insert roster (country,state,city) values ('usa','kentucky','blah_blah');
```

and for strings I use

```
select * from roster r
join 
(SELECT min(id) as cheatId
FROM roster
where country='usa' and state='kentucky') inr
on inr.cheatId=r.id

+----+---------+----------+------------+---------+
| id | country | state    | city       | cheatId |
+----+---------+----------+------------+---------+
|  1 | usa     | kentucky | louisville |       1 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And for **objects** you use:

```
select r from roster r
join 
(SELECT min(id) as cheatId
FROM roster
where country=:country and state=:state) inr
on inr.cheatId=r.id
```

Comment: My issue is I need to return the object and that would return the string? I wish it was that simple!

Comment: what is your `show create table Roster` ... can you plop that in your question with Edit button

Comment: That's quite brilliant actually. Very sneaky way of pulling one out. I like it. I will try implementing it later and report back. But that looks great. Thanks a lot Drew. It's past midnight here and I need to get some rest. Will update tomorrow.